# Trait dependency loading in sequence

Tags: php, sorting, oop, traits

I'm currently working on a trait auto initializer and its all working fine and dandy however there are sadly some severe limitations on traits.

One issue I came across is the following:

```
trait constructor{}
trait cache{}
trait database{}
trait settings{} # requires database or cache.
```

Now for my auto loading system to work I must define the use in the correct sequence like so:

```
class t{
  use constructor, cache, settings;
}
```

If I would do the following:

```
class t{
  use constructor, settings, cache;
}
```

The settings trait initializer will be called before the cache initializer and thus the `$cache` variable inside the cache trait is null.

Now a simple solution would be to add `use cache, database;` to the settings trait however that can result in collisions of defined methods if used by another trait that must be included.

Another solution would be to check if the property `$cache` is defined and then check if it's set but this would create a lot of redundant code I'd rather not want to write for each and every trait.

Now the logic of the code is the following:

```
trait constructor{
  function init(){
    echo 'I am called first';
    print_r(class_uses(self::class))/*[
      'constructor' => 'constructor',
      'cache' => 'cache',
      'database' => 'database',
      'settings' => 'settings'

      // Sorted in sequence as defined in the class.
    ]*/

    # now call other trait initializers.
  }
}

trait settings{
  function settings(){
    echo 'I am called last, but before __construct()';
  }
}

class t{
  use constructor; // required by all traits
  use cache;       // requires constructor.
  use database;    // requires constructor.
  use settings;    // requires constructor, cache || database.

  function __construct(){
    echo 'I am called after init()';
    $this->db->prepare(...)->execute();
  }
}
```

It is in the constructor possible to sort the array to make sure the settings is indexed after cache or database. However here comes the tricky part, what is the *best* approach to do this?

Since most classes only use a small number of traits, defining a lengthy array to use as a base for sorting seems deficient. As this system is running at the core of the CMS I'd rather sort on a trait by trait basis.

The problem with traits is that I cannot define the same thing twice, noor in class as well so I'd like to keep the scope pollution to a minimum.

Comment: Interesting. We've been having dependency issues with traits (and/or the client classes loading them) and decided to refrain from their use and instead use proper classes we can dependency-inject. However, in some cases this is rather the lesser evil than a good solution. Just wondering, which PHP version do you target? I ask because there were some changes between 5.4 and 5.6 and maybe also between 5 and 7.

Comment: I am currently rewriting specifically for PHP 7, however the code used to make this magic happen is very much compatible with 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a viable solution to the issue without too much redundant code.

```
trait constructor{
  private $traits;

  function loaded(array $list){
    foreach($list as $trait){
      if(isset($this->_traits[$trait])){ // class_uses returns array of ['trait' => 'trait'] while I append numeric.
        $this->_traits[] = $this->_current; // append the current looping method (of init) to be loaded last.
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  function init(){
    $traits = class_uses(self::class);
    while(list(,$method) = each($this->traits)){
      unset($this->_traits[$method]); // avoid infinite loop.
      // This while loop will loop trough newly added values added by 'loaded' 
      call_user_func([$this, $method]);
    }
  }
}

trait settings{
  function settings(){
    if($this->loaded(['cache', 'database'])){
      # This method will queue the 'settings' method for later regardless if the traits are already loaded.
      # So it will first load the traits that don't have dependency's.
      # The order is not important because the __construct method is called last anyways.
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any other suggestion, just add an answer.